# Why was my question deleted

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions, automatic-deletion

A few months ago I made this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62110306/is-there-any-way-to-export-all-the-urls-from-a-google-search-result

It proceeded to immediately get a single downvote and be forgotten. Now it's deleted. I still want to know the answer to that question.

---

[image]

Comment: Your question is off topic as it is a resource request.  Even if it gets undeleted, it would likely get closed and deleted again because of this.

Comment: Roomba is working as expected and as hoped

Comment: @Daedalus, where should I ask for such resources, then?

Comment: @AndreM962 Not here.

Comment: @Daedalus Well, obviously, but there's really no Stackoverflow for that kind of thing?

Comment: @AndreM962 the fact Stack attracted the experts you want to answer these questions is... .cause it doesn't allow these questions. Ironic, heh? The experts expect to be paid for this kinda stuff :/... Nowhere on the Stack ecosystem are these type of questions really appropriate.

Answer (score 16):

It was deleted because it was closed and you didn't edit it to address the reason for closure so it could be reopened.

If you're not going to edit the question into a form that we can accept then there's not much point in keeping it around. You had quite some time to edit it if you wanted to, it was deleted by an automatic process and that does wait to see if you're going to edit it.

Comment: Nitpick: it was never closed. [Roomba deleted it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62110306/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) as a "dead question".